# filling only half of Matrix using OpenMp in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, openmp

I have a quite big matrix. I would like to fill half of the matrix in parallel. 
m_matrix is 2D std vector. Any suggestion for the type of container is appreciated as well. What _fill(i,j) function is doing is **not** considered heavy **compared to size of the matrix**.

```
//i: row
//j: column

  for (size_t i=1; i<num_row; ++i)
    {
    for (size_t j=0; j<i; ++j)
      {
      m_matrix[i][j] = _fill(i, j);
      }
    }
```

What would be a nice openMP structure for that?  I tried dynamic strategy bet I got even time increase compared to the sequential mode.

Comment: What does `_fill` do, does it have state? What type is `m_matrix`?

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: By *2D std vector*, do you mean `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`? Does `_fill` access any static or global variables? Also if the computation is *not heavy*, why do you specifically target this for parallelization - rather than actual computational intense operations on the data?

Comment: yes, I meant vector < vector<> > . vectors are resized to the proper size values. However since my matrix is massive I would like to do it in parallel. In sequential mode, it takes couple of minutes.

Comment: if `_fill(i, j)` is not heavy, then the bottleneck of this operation is the memory bandwidth, not the CPU calculation, and you won't get a significant speedup by paralleling your code (if any)

Comment: _not considered heavy compared to size of the matrix_ - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it is not a really heavy job. and I am aware of the situation that for the light functions it is better to run them in sequential.

Comment: @undermind That's true, but there are several levels of memory bandwidth limits. Increasing cores might be beneficial because it could utilize more of low level cache. It's hard to tell with out analyzing actual code.

Comment: @luk32 Right, but if the matrix is large then after all we need to write almost all the data from caches to RAM (because only the small part of matrix can fit in the caches even from all cores). And writes from caches to RAM are sequential. But, yes, the code needs to be profiled decently to be sure.

Comment: The amount of queries in comments shows that this question needs a [mcve]. It is easy to answer the question itself, but this itself many not be helpful due to an XY problem.

Comment: @H'H You can try the following: replace the inner loop with the loop `for (size_t j=0; j<num_col; ++j)` and make sure all calls to `_fill(i, j)` take approximately the same time. Then, if after paralleling the outer loop you won't get a speedup, you'll be sure that the problem is not in load imbalance.